Mark 13:30: Did Jesus' words fail or prove to be untrue?
Mark 13:30 says:
30 Truly I tell you, this generation will certainly not pass away until all these things have happened. 31 Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will never pass away.
Well, the generation that heard these words of Jesus has passed away , and the Son of Man did not come (apparently). Does this mean that the prophecy made by Jesus failed?

Read When Prophecy Fails: A Social and Psychological Study of a Modern Group That Predicted the Destruction of the World.

Even if this wasn't a duplicate, prophecy fulfilment questions are almost always off-topic.

Yes, it is failed, if we read original word γενεά (G1074) as 'time-spatially collective people, i.e. generation'. No, it is not failed, if we read γενεά as 'kindred, type'.
The problem comes from the fact, that this word can be equally applied to text in sense of 'human bloodline', and in sense of 'human kindline', so called here for the sake of contrast.
So, what is the proper must to read it in mentioned verse?
Mark 13:30:


[TR] ἀμὴν λέγω ὑμῖν ὅτι οὐ μὴ παρέλθῃ ἡ γενεὰ αὕτη μέχρις οὗ πάντα ταῦτα γένηται
[YLT] Verily I say to you, that this generation may not pass away till all these things may come to pass;


Let's see some other verses to have a picture of talks being told.

Mark 9:29:


[TR] καὶ εἶπεν αὐτοῖς Τοῦτο τὸ γένος ἐν οὐδενὶ δύναται ἐξελθεῖν εἰ μὴ ἐν προσευχῇ Καὶ νηστείᾳ
[YLT] And he said to them, 'This kind is able to come forth with nothing except with prayer and fasting.'


Here, it is doubtless that what meant to be read here is 'kindred, type', and according to that, - singular masculine γένος (G1085) was chosen, to distinct special one among other species of similar kindline - unclean spirits of disease (Mark 9:17).
What is to note here, that there must be some way to express whole this kindline with single word, which is quantitatively singular too.

Matthew 17:17:


[TR] ἀποκριθεὶς δὲ ὁ Ἰησοῦς εἶπεν Ὦ γενεὰ ἄπιστος καὶ διεστραμμένη ἕως πότε ἔσομαι μεθ᾽ ὑμῶν ἕως πότε ἀνέξομαι ὑμῶν φέρετέ μοι αὐτὸν ὧδε
[YLT] And Jesus answering said, 'O generation, unstedfast and perverse, till when shall I be with you? till when shall I bear you? bring him to me hither;'


Here, according to previous verses of the chapter, it is definitely right to read γενεὰ as 'jewish bloodline', due to the fact of scribes and Elijah Baptist being mentioned. But, what easy to miss here is the fact that a single person, who held jewish bloodline, comes to Jesus with a problem of his son being possessed by unclean spirit.
That said, it is definitely right too - to read γενεὰ here as 'kindline of cursed spirits'; - because Jesus just covered inquiries from two with one take, due to the fact that them both approached him as an instance of the single person, one man, a jew. Very important to note, that possessed one was the son of that man. (who is the father of lie and unclean spirits?..)

Acts 8:33:


[TR] Ἐν τῇ ταπεινώσει αὐτοῦ ἡ κρίσις αὐτοῦ ἤρθη· τὴν δὲ γενεὰν αὐτοῦ τίς διηγήσεται ὅτι αἴρεται ἀπὸ τῆς γῆς ἡ ζωὴ αὐτοῦ
[YLT] in his humiliation his judgment was taken away, and his generation -- who shall declare? because taken from the earth is his life.'


in Acts 8:29-35, we see the clearest sense of '(head of) kindline of clean spirits' being placed under the word γενεά. In verse 33 where it is, we actually face a quote from Old Testament, what makes everything said here - more affirmed and consistent.

Acts 14:16:


[TR] ὃς ἐν ταῖς παρῳχημέναις γενεαῖς εἴασεν πάντα τὰ ἔθνη πορεύεσθαι ταῖς ὁδοῖς αὐτῶν·
[YLT] who in the past generations did suffer all the nations to go on in their ways,


This one is tricky, but important too, because here we see clear usage of γενεαῖς only in a sense of 'human kindlines', while word ἔθνη holds a single sense of 'human bloodlines' here.
The point to use γενεά (G1074) in plural here is to state, that God have never left away from humans completely, and if any γενεά (kindline) among γενεαῖς (kindlines) of all ἔθνη (nations) was clean one, then God for sure was present among such people. This point is confirmed right in the next verse, and being so crucial, is expressed in one of John's letters very clearly.
1 John 2:29:


[TR] ἐὰν εἰδῆτε ὅτι δίκαιός ἐστιν γινώσκετε ὅτι πᾶς ὁ ποιῶν τὴν δικαιοσύνην ἐξ αὐτοῦ γεγέννηται
[YLT] if ye know that he [Jesus] is righteous, know ye that every one doing the righteousness, of him hath been begotten.




That was an argumentation based on words' comparative usage in New Testament, while the sense, which we must uncover in Mark 13:30, - is present in Old Testament too, even though it is lying under different words.
Deuteronomy 31:16:


[LXX] καὶ εἶπεν κύριος πρὸς Μωυσῆν ἰδοὺ σὺ κοιμᾷ μετὰ τῶν πατέρων σου καὶ ἀναστὰς ὁ λαὸς οὗτος ἐκπορνεύσει ὀπίσω θεῶν ἀλλοτρίων τῆς γῆς εἰς ἣν οὗτος εἰσπορεύεται ἐκεῖ εἰς αὐτήν καὶ ἐγκαταλείψουσίν με καὶ διασκεδάσουσιν τὴν διαθήκην μου ἣν διεθέμην αὐτοῖς
[YLT] And Jehovah saith unto Moses, 'Lo, thou art lying down with thy fathers, and this people hath risen, and gone a-whoring after the gods of the stranger of the land into the midst of which it hath entered, and forsaken Me, and broken My covenant which I made with it;


Deuteronomy 32:50:


[LXX] καὶ τελεύτα ἐν τῷ ὄρει εἰς ὃ ἀναβαίνεις ἐκεῖ καὶ προστέθητι πρὸς τὸν λαόν σου ὃν τρόπον ἀπέθανεν Ααρων ὁ ἀδελφός σου ἐν Ωρ τῷ ὄρει καὶ προσετέθη πρὸς τὸν λαὸν αὐτοῦ
[YLT] and die in the mount whither thou art going up, and be gathered unto thy people, as Aaron thy brother hath died in the mount Hor, and is gathered unto his people:


Here, we don't find γενεά (G1074) or γένος (G1085), but the λαός (G2992).
And finally, let me put my answer here in a form of a question:

Do you think that "this people" from 31:16, who definitely held jewish bloodline, are the same people from 32:50, who definitely held jewish bloodline too?


In brief
In light of all said, Jesus' words seems to be proven  true by Scripture, because sense under words of Mark 13:30 is factual: cursed kindline is present for sure, Jesus has not yet came for sure.

One of the disciples had pointed out the beauty of Herod's temple, to which Jesus responded:

"Seest thou these great buildings? There shall not be left one stone
upon another that shall not be thrown down." Mark 13:1-2 A.V.

The next verse has Peter, James, Andrew and John asking Jesus, while they sat on the Mount of Olives looking towards the temple, what sign - singular - to look for regarding when that prophecy had been fulfilled. It was as if they believed the temple would be destroyed, but that they really wanted to know about events thereafter. In Matthew's gospel account (chapter 24), there is the interesting phrase, "the sign of thy coming, and of the end of the world". But, sticking to Mark...
Jesus' answer to the four apostle's question takes from verse 5 to 23. All of that applied to the sign of the temple's destruction, and how to avoid being caught up in the destruction - how, and where to flee. The sign they had to look for was an abomination that causes desolation standing where it ought not; then they had to flee to the mountains. History shows that Roman armies camped around Jerusalem, but then were suddenly recalled. That allowed Christian in and around Jerusalem to flee to the mountains. Then the Roman armies returned a bit later, so that in A.D. 70 the city had been captured, the temple utterly destroyed, and massive deaths plus slaves captured. That happened within the generational lifetime of the apostles.
This means that "that generation" of Christians who were obedient to acting on the sign Jesus gave them knew that his words had been proven true.
This means, then, that the rest of what he said about "after that tribulation..." (Mark 13:24) would apply to another generation: not the one that saw the destruction of Jerusalem in A.D. 70, but one that would witness another tribulation heralding the return of Jesus Christ.
This is in accord with Jesus warning his followers not to be deceived in the lead-up to Jerusalem's destruction, by paying attention to others claiming that Jesus had already returned. Only, they would have to come into their inner rooms, or out into the wilderness, to see this claimed returned Christ. Jesus explicitly warned them not to be deceived by such false claims:

"And then if any man shall say to you, Lo, here is Christ, or, lo, he
is there, believe him not: for false Christs and false prophets shall
rise, and shall shew signs and wonders, to seduce, if it were
possible, even the elect" verse 22, A.V.

This indicates that Jesus was saying he would not return at the time of the destruction of Jerusalem. This is confirmed by the parable he gave of a man making a far journey, not returning till much later at an unspecified time, to see whether his servants in charge had done their job (vss. 33-35).
Only after Jesus had died, was resurrected, and was seen ascending back to heaven, would the disciples understand that parable. Only then would they be able to see the 'double meaning' of the prophecy; initial fulfillment within that generation of the destruction of the temple; second fulfillment within a future generation suffering great tribulation and far more powerful signs. Those were detailed by the apostle John in the book of the Revelation, many years after the temple's destruction.
So, the answer to the question is that Jesus' prophetic words proved true within that generation that did see the temple's destruction, giving assurance to the future generation that will see Christ's return and "the end of the world", that the greater, global fulfillment is guaranteed.

If your question is not rhetorical, then it is sacrilegious.
The drama of the End of the World and fight of Christ and Antichrist will happen by the end of history and nobody can tell when exactly, in two thousand years, or three hundred years, or fifteen years. However, the inner, the essential, the spiritual side of the drama has been lived and will be lived by all humans of all generations, for either you are in the camp of Antichrist and persecute Christ and His servants, or you are in the camp of Christ and are persecuted. Tertium non datur.
Therefore, the LORD’s words that “this generation will not pass before all this will happen” applies to all generations. The intensity of struggle between Christ and Antichrist is the same in all generations, to the effect that Christians of the last years and months of human history persecuted by the last Antichrist, will not suffer any more than Christians persecuted by modern-day Antichrists.
Christ never lies, He does not nay cannot; when He told His brothers that He will not go to the feast they were going to, but then He went there, He did not lie, but said truth: the feast of His brothers was to be vaingloriously popular together with Him being on a spotlight; but this was not Christ’s feast; so, He went to the same place, same time, but not to the same feast, but to a different feast (cf. John 7:7-10).

NO.  Jesus kept His promise.  The problem is with the false dogma that has been taught for centuries that His 2nd coming was for the purpose of the end of the physical world.  The "literalists" who cannot recognize and have not learned the metaphorical and symbolic nature of God's apocalyptic judgment language has caused this great error and confusion.
The end times or last days are defined in the scriptures as the last days of each of the tribes of Israel, especially that of Judah, the law giver.

The sceptre turneth not aside from Judah, And a lawgiver from between his feet, Till his Seed come; And his [is] the obedience of peoples. (Gen. 49:10, YLT)

The scepter was passed from the tribe of Judah to Christ, the promised Seed through Isaac, the promised son, when John the grandson of the last true Zadok High Priest baptized Jesus in the Jordan river.  That was the anointing when the Holy Spirit descended as a dove upon Christ (Matt. 3:16; Mark 1:10; Luke 3:22).  That marked the transfer of the priesthood from an earthly priest to the spiritual priest that Christ would put on after the order of Melchizedek (Psa. 110:4; Heb. 7:14-21).
The last days were the last days of that old Mosaic covenant, which ended with the destruction of Jerusalem and that old animal sacrificial temple which became profane once Christ became the last blood sacrifice God would ever again accept for forgiveness of sins.  The destruction of that temple was the second coming, the second appearance promised to that generation which saw His first appearance in earthly manifestation during His 3-1/2 year ministry, His death, His resurrection, and His ascension into heaven.
Only that generation could have a second appearance of Him, as no other generation since then has seen Him in the flesh.  A coming of the Lord was the phrase used in the old Testament for a day of judgment, a time of judgment, a day of vengeance, or a day of His wrath.  All of those comings were times of judgment against wicked people who would not repent nor turn back to God.
That was the condition of those first century Jews who despised the promised Messiah, and delivered Him up to the Romans demanding He be crucified.

Lo, he doth come with the clouds, and see him shall every eye, even those who did pierce him, and wail because of him shall all the tribes of the land. Yes! Amen! (Rev. 1:7, YLT)

Who pierced Him?  When was He pierced?  Was any other generation guilty of those acts?  Only that generation was promised that judgment, and He carried it out just as He foretold His disciples in Matt. 24. Mark 13, Luke 21, and all of Revelation (John's Olivet discourse).

and Jesus said to them, `Do ye not see all these? verily I say to you, There may not be left here a stone upon a stone, that shall not be thrown down.'


3 And when he is sitting on the mount of the Olives, the disciples came near to him by himself, saying, `Tell us, when shall these be? and what [is] the sign of thy presence, and of the full end of the age?'  (Matt. 24:2-3, YLT)

The disciples knew that the destruction of their temple was the end of the age, the end of their world as they knew it.
The scriptures must be read from the first audience perspective.  We are not living in the end times.  They were.  The prophecy of the destruction of the temple, and all the works that were going on on that earth of Judea / Jerusalem was for that generation.  Not our generation, but their generation.
The destruction of Jerusalem and the temple at the hands of the Romans in AD 70 ushered in the everlasting spiritual kingdom of God, the spiritual city of the new Jerusalem, and the full rule of Christ over all kingdoms on earth.
Christ did not lie to His disciples.  We can trust every word that He spoke.  We can put our full faith and belief that He did everything He said He would do.
See these posts with more scripture proofs at my blog post:
Did Christ Lie to His Disciples?
...The Time of His Coming
...Where Was All The World?
Daniel and the End Times
Testing The Spirits - Part II: The End
